# Best database design to store html pages?

Tags: database-design, nosql, database-performance

I need to store HTML pages, along with their HTML tags, and images (or link to an image) into some kind of database.
Each day would be written more than 500K web pages. This number will increase in time. Those writes are done by many systems spread in the world.

I was looking around for some technologies that fit my needs and I found some interesting ones, like: MongoDB, HBase, Cassandra, Scylla, ElasticSearch/Solr.

Which one is the better choice?
Do I need one of those or mixing it is the best solution? i.e. Cassandra + ElasticSearch (I don't have idea how to implement such configuration but I read of people that uses that mix).

Reading all around, documentations and blogs, I would say that Cassandra would fit my needs because I can expand the structure whenever I want adding more nodes when needed. Writes/reads performance are pretty good and the configuration I need is quite standard and it seems much easier than HBase.
The only problem is that Cassandra, as well as HBase, can have only one index to use for querying.

From my point of view, I would like to reach the minimum cost and the best flexibility I can have (of course, anyone wants that).

I don't know the correct design I need to use.
do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

how can you compare hbase / elasticsearch / mongodb ?? they are all different technologies, it depends on your skills / needs.

Do you need full text search ?  do you have enough skills to setup Hadoop for HBase ?

Personaly, I would suggest to write HTML content in files (inside HDFS, as web archive or inside S3), and store pages metas (title / headers / description / URL) inside elasticsearch for fast search.

Comment: thank for your answer. Actually, I don't compare anything. Those technologies simply get me the same "result", that is html pages and other minor stuff are stored somewhere. In fact, the question aims to understand which one fits my needs. 
If you talk about skills, I don't have any skill for those technologies, yet. I am in a studying phase right now. If I will need some skills I will get them.
Thanks for you suggestion about storing HTML pages into files inside HDFS and metas into ES. I will take it into account.